# Que veut dire l'expression « bon vivant » ?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, sens

J'ai entendu l'expression « bon vivant » pour décrire la vie de certaines personnes. Que veut-elle dire, exactement ? Quelqu'un pourrait-il élaborer un peu ?

Comment: This can be found in online dictionaries, can it not? [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivant/substantif), [Wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_vivant)

Comment: It's not necessarily easy for non-francophones to really grasp though because I'm not sure we really have any kind of direct translation.

Comment: [Là, ils élaborent beaucoup :·)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X63HBt_q3YY)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Bon vivant" désigne une personne qui aime les bonnes choses de la vie, notamment la nourriture et les boissons raffinées (les plaisirs de la table).

Le terme formel pour désigner cela est "épicurien" (conforme à la doctrine d'[Épicure](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C9picure)).

#### Edit:

Suite à discussion dans le chat

L'expression s'utilise comme un nom seulement, et n'est pas un adjectif. "Marc est un bon vivant"

Comment: D'après le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vivant/substantif) : _Personne d'humeur joviale qui apprécie les plaisirs de la vie._

Comment: Pour être pointilleux, un épicurien ne suit pas vraiment la doctrine d'Épicure, mais l'idée (fausse) qu'on s'en est fait au travers des âges. Épicure ne recommandait pas d'aimer "les bonnes choses de la vie", mais de considérer les plaisirs naturels (manger à sa faim, boire à sa soif, être abrité du froid, vivre en compagnie d'amis fidèles) sans outre mesure. Il ne faut pas confondre la doctrine d'Épicure avec les hédonistes ou les cyrénaïques, qui eux prêchaient la débauche.

Comment: @subtenante +1 Stoïcisme et épicurisme sont deux "doctrines" qui ont très mal été transposées dans la "connaissance commune".

Answer (score -1):

The literal meaning of "bon vivant" is someone who "lives well."

A figurative meaning is someone who is a "man about town" goes to fancy restaurants, dates pretty women, etc. Probably drives an expensive, flashy car, and maybe has some expensive vices such as gambling or taking drugs. The Anglo-American equivalent might be "high roller."

Le sens littéral de "bon vivant" est c'est quelqu'un qui vit bien.

Le sens figuré, c'est quelqu'un qui est un "homme de la ville" va à des restaurants coûteux, et couche avec des jolies femmes. L'équivalent anglo-américain pourrait être "high roller."

Comment: Ça me semble assez peu lié à la notion d'argent, et même assez incompatible avec certaines des idées mentionnées.

Comment: Selon la response de M'vy, "Bon vivant" désigne une personne qui aime les bonnes choses de la vie, notamment la nourriture et les boissons raffinées (les plaisirs de la table)." "Un "homme de la ville" va à des restaurants coûteux," est d'accord avec cette reponse.  Ma continuation, "et couche avec des jolies femmes. L'équivalent anglo-américain pourrait être high roller," est COMPLEMENTAIRE
 avec cette reponse.